# Getting nested JSON array and objects and facing Json Exception

Tags: android, json, getjson

This is the Nested Json Array that we are getting as a respone from server side.

**Response:**

```
"[[{\"userID\":\"1\",\"roleID\":\"1\",\"userName\":\"GHG Admin\",\"email\":\"vikas.rana@redalkemi.in\",\"password\":\"b2314cd68cdfb7545dacd0b4ecf6a190\",\"userImage\":\"image12.jpg\",\"dtAdded\":\"2013-05-28\",\"dtUpdated\":\"2013-05-28\",\"enumStatus\":\"A\"}],[{\"settingID\":\"1\",\"moduleName\":\"event\",\"displayName\":\"Ev\\\"ent's1\",\"enumStatus\":\"E\"},{\"settingID\":\"2\",\"moduleName\":\"notice\",\"displayName\":\"Not\\\"ic'es\",\"enumStatus\":\"E\"},{\"settingID\":\"3\",\"moduleName\":\"quote\",\"displayName\":\"Qu\\\"ot'es\",\"enumStatus\":\"E\"},{\"settingID\":\"6\",\"moduleName\":\"crawlingtext\",\"displayName\":\"Crawling Text\",\"enumStatus\":\"D\"}]]"
```

Here is the code for getting this, but while executing complier goes in catch JSON exeception.

```
JSONArray arr;
try {
            if (response != null) {

        System.out.println(response);

                                arr= new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONArray a1= arr.getJSONArray(0);
                                JSONObject  obj1= a1.getJSONObject(0);
                                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                                    map.put("userID", obj1.getString("userID"));
                                    map.put("userName", obj1.getString("userName"));


                                    data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                                    data.add(map);
                                    id = (String) map.get("userID");
                                    ID=Integer.parseInt(id);
                                    name = (String) map.get("userName");
                                    System.out.println(id+name);

                                JSONArray a2=arr.getJSONArray(1);   
                                for (int i = 0; i < a2.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject obj2= a2.getJSONObject(i);
                                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put("settingID", obj2.getString("settingID"));
                                map.put("moduleName", obj2.getString("moduleName"));
                                data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                                data.add(map);
                                String Module=(String)map.get("moduleName");
                                        System.out.println("MODULE="+Module);

                    }}
                    }



                            catch ( JSONException e ) {
                                System.out.println("JSON Error parsing JSON");
                            }
```

Comment: Indent your JSON data and also your code for legible content.

Comment: Usually JSONException is self-explanatory. What does your exception say?

Comment: Try your json in http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, you will get a good idea how your json is formatted

Comment: Complier is not executing the loops or try code but only showing exception message

Comment: @Aparana Print stack trace in `catch` clause, e.g. `e.printStacktrace();` and show us logcat logs.

Comment: Its not correct format of `JSON`. Ask your php developer to correct it. `\` slashes add only when you try to create a `JSONObject` which is already a `JSONObject`

Comment: @AnshulTyagi thanks for your help, PHP developer correct the format.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't removed the escape sequences from the JSON response before parsing it. Do this before you parse the response

```
response.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","");
arr= new JSONArray(response);
....
```